# javascript: .innerHTML in to table not adding new rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

My js is not adding rows to the end of my table
HTML:

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%" id="tbLIFE">
    <tr><th colspan="3">LifePath</th></tr>
    <tr><th colspan="3">Style</th></tr>
    <tr id="LifeEvents"></tr>
</table>
```

js:

```
//LIFE EVENTS
var d61 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
var d62 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
var Age = d61+d62+16;

document.getElementById("LifeEvents").innerHTML = "<th colspan=3 id='lifeEvents'>Life Events</th>";
document.getElementById("LifeEvents").innerHTML += "</tr><tr><td>Age</td><td>"+Age+"</td>";
```

i dont mind useing jquery.

Comment: Why is your `th` closed with the `td` ? `<tr><th colspan="3">Style</td></tr>`

Comment: @MysterX just a typo when posting the question :P

Comment: @GuruprasadRao please elaborate

Comment: **[Your above code works fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/0jav6t06/1/)** What is the problem then?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao it adds the `</tr><tr><td>Age</td><td>"+Age+"</td>` to the side of the row instead of under it

Comment: that's the way you've designed it to be.. Can you visualize how you want your table to be?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao it [should look like this](https://jsfiddle.net/e3udw94r/) when the js is done

Comment: **[You need to append the 2nd `tr` to table instead of `#LifeEvents`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/0jav6t06/2/)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao perfect thankyou

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :) I am removing my first comment as I haven't read your question properly.. I missed the element with id `LifeEvents` and that's what made me to ask that question.. Sorry for that..

Answer (score 0):

As provided by @Guruprasad Rao

```
var d61 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
var d62 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
var Age = d61+d62+16;

document.getElementById("LifeEvents").innerHTML = "<th colspan=3 id='lifeEvents'>Life Events</th>";
document.getElementById("tbLIFE").innerHTML += "<tr><td>Age</td><td>"+Age+"</td>";
```